# List Only main Packages with pip list

Tags: python, pip

With `pip list`, we can see the install packages in our environment. There is no problem with that. We can also write them to a req.txt file with pip freeze and quickly load them in other environments with this req.txt file. My question here is, for example, when we install `pandas`, libraries such as `numpy` are installed with them, and we can see other libraries installed outside of pandas with `pip list`. Can I use an option with `pip list` to see only the main libraries I have installed here? For example, is there an option to show only pandas (no libraries like numpy) when I do a pip list?

Comment: "Can I use an option with pip list to see only the main libraries I have installed here?" Usually that information should be found in the setup.py, setup.cfg, or pyproject.toml of the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `--not-required` flag. This will [list packages that are not dependencies of installed packages](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/#cmdoption-not-required)<sup>pip.pypa.io</sup>.

```
python -m pip list --not-required
```

or if `pip` is in *`$PATH`*

```
pip list --not-required
```